# Xamarin.iOS New Project (Single View, Master-Detail) crashes on Simulator, works on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I create a new project in Xamarin Studio for Mac. 
When running this project on Simulator, app crashes immediately after launch. Even before any screen is shown. On Device it is working.

I'm using Xamarin Studio for Mac with alpha channel updates. Now it 5.2 build 379.

Application source code is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7022824/TestApp2.zip

Application output when I start the app:

```
Starting iPhone Retina (4-inch)
Launching application
Application launched. PID = 8715
Press enter to terminate the application
>
Application Terminated
```

Application crashes on Simulator, starts and works on iOS device.

Comment: Which Xcode version do you have?

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge I have 5.1.1

Comment: There are known problems with the current stable version of Xcode and the current Xamarin.iOS alpha (the alpha contains iOS 8 support, and has almost exclusively been tested with Xcode 6 for now; there are known bugs with older versions of Xcode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: link SDK assemblies only. It seems there are some problems with linker

Comment: I am glad we solved this problem. Specifying Link SDK assemblies only made app launching on simulator.

Comment: This solved the problem of the app not starting - but it added a new problem, namely, you cant set breakpoints in any PCL projects linked into your iOS project anymore (they just get ignored)